# if user enters two words for Scanner's next(), the second word is transferred to the nextInt() method that follows causing an inputMismatchException

Tags: java, string, integer, java.util.scanner, user-input

```
System.out.println("Enter guest surName");
String roomName = input.next();
int num = input.nextInt();
```

For example when I enter "Michael Jackson" I get this error.

```
Enter guest surName
Michael Jackson
Exception in thread "main" java.util.InputMismatchException
    at java.util.Scanner.throwFor(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.Scanner.next(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.Scanner.nextInt(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.Scanner.nextInt(Unknown Source)
    at test4.Demo.main(Demo.java:13)
```

I understand that the error is caused because the second word is passed on to the  nextInt() method. But I don't know how to resolve it.

And  I cannot use nextLine() due to the nature of the rest of the program.

Comment: Why can't you use next line? It doesn't make a difference in the snippet you've shown, except that you will no longer get your input missmatch error.

Answer (score 3):

You could change the delimiter of the scanner object. Default is whitespace

```
input.useDelimiter("\n");
```

For example, this will wait until the line is finished.
And then you could use next () to properly catch the input.

If you can't use next Line () though, you should change the delimiter back to whitespace after the input. To avoid any inconveniences that I'm not aware of.

Answer (score 2):

You want to do `nextLine` instead of `next`: [doc here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#nextLine--)

```
String roomName = input.nextLine();

System.out.println("Enter guest number");
int num = input.nextInt();
```

Answer (score 0):

instead of `String roomName = input.next();` use `String roomName = input.nextLine();`

```
Scanner input= new Scanner(System.in);
System.out.println("Enter guest surName");
String roomName = input.nextLine();
int num = input.nextInt();
```

Answer (score 0):

Try with below code:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
class Test{

public static void main (String args[]){

Scanner input= new Scanner(System.in);
System.out.println("Enter guest surName");
String roomName = input.next();
System.out.println("roomName  ="+roomName );

String num = input.nextLine();
System.out.println("num ="+num );

}
}
```